# A real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis

$\Omega$ is an open set in $R^n$. Given any $\delta>0$, and any $u \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, is it possible that we can find $v\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ such that $|u-v|_{L^p} < \delta$, and we can control the derivative of $v$, like, $|D_{x_i}v|_{L^p}<M$, for any $i=1,\ldots,n$? Thank you for any help!